# How do I cast String column of Dataframe As Struct in Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently using Structured Streaming to consume messages from Kafka

This message in its orignal format has the following schema structure

```
root
 |-- incidentMessage: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- AssignedUnitEvent: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- CallNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- EventDateTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- EventDispatcherID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Notes: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- PhoneNumberCalled: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- SubCallNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- SupItemNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- UnitID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- preamble: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- gateway: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- product: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- psap: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- refDataVersion: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- uuid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- vendor: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
 |-- raw: string (nullable = true)
```

However I made an error in defining the schema  for the message (in the streaming component) and I wrote 
code that casts all the root columns as String.

This is the code I wrote

```
//Define the schema

val schema1 = new StructType().add("preamble",DataTypes.StringType).add("incidentMessage",DataTypes.StringType).add("raw",DataTypes.StringType)

//Apply the schema to the message (payload)

val finalResult = Df.withColumn("FinalFrame",from_json($"payload",schema1)).select($"FinalFrame.*")
```

Now my dataframe looks like this

```
scala> finalResult.printSchema
root
 |-- incidentMessage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- preamble: string (nullable = true)
 |-- raw: string (nullable = true)
```

I now have a large set of messages with incorrect schema.I have tried applying the proper schema to the messages I have right now but the set of messages written to the filesystem  have variable schemas( there are changes in the nested columns of incidentMessage) and this approach does not work (I messed up, should have used Avro)

Is there a way to recover this data and have it in the correct format?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data (just one line), and tell us what output schema or what output data you expect?

Answer (score 5):

although it does not make much sense to create e struct with just 1 field, you can do it with `struct` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct

df.withColumn("incidentMessage",struct($"incidentMessage"))
```